# how to set height by percentage in tbody vertical scroll in javascript?

Tags: html, css

I use vertical scrollbar in tbody.
Below is my css style.

```
 table > tbody
{
 display: block;
 max-height: 400px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}

table > thead, tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

But the table container has dynamic size, so i want to set it's height to 100%. (
max-height: 100%;)
But it does not work with percentage. It must work with pixel.
How should i gonna set tbody's height (all maxheight) 100%?

This table has wrapped by parent div container and the height 100% means that 
i want to fill 100% the div container by this table , and i want to put vertical scroll in tbody.

P.S
Maybe the javascript will the way.. but is there have any way to use only css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with HTML or CSS because `<div>` will provide the height based on its content whether you provide any particular `height` or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Then i must use js to calculate and set the height?

Comment: you cant set the height of any of the elements inside the tag table, what you can do is set the height of the tag table to 100% that way will have the same height that his container